Delete last row with value then find
I have a google script that delete row that contain value of active cell
function deleteshift() {
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sheet = ss.getSheetByName('main');
let dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('deletDB');
let existingId = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
let existing = dataSheet.getRange(2,6,dataSheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues().flat();
let index = existing.indexOf(existingId);

if (index != -1) { dataSheet.deleteRow(index + 2); } }

This script starts from the top row but how can I start from last row and delete the first entry from last to up.

Instead of indexOf, use lastIndexOf:
const index = existing.lastIndexOf(existingId);


Deleting First Entry from Last to Up
I modified your code and created a sample data, this is the result.
Code.gs
function deleteshift() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('main');
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('deletDB');
  const existingId = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
  const existing = dataSheet.getRange(2, 6, dataSheet.getLastRow() - 1).getValues().flat();

  const index = (existing.length - existing.reverse().indexOf(existingId))  + 1;
  dataSheet.deleteRow(index);
}

Sample Data
Before:


After:


Reference:

Array Methods


Providing additional explanations for this code:
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
retrieves the currently active Google Sheets document.
const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('main');
accesses the sheet named "main."
const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('deletDB'); accesses another sheet named "deletDB."
const existingId = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue(); gets the value from the currently active cell in the "main" sheet, storing it as existingId. This value is used to identify which row to delete.
const lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow(); gets the index of the last row in the "deletDB" sheet.
A for loop starts at lastRow and moves upwards (towards the top), stopping at row 2.
If cellValue matches existingId, dataSheet.deleteRow(i); deletes row i and the loop breaks, stopping further iteration.
function deleteShiftFromLastRow() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('main');
  const dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('deletDB');
  const existingId = sheet.getActiveCell().getValue();
  const lastRow = dataSheet.getLastRow();

  for (let i = lastRow; i >= 2; i--) {
    const cellValue = dataSheet.getRange(i, 6).getValue();
    if (cellValue === existingId) {
      dataSheet.deleteRow(i);
      break;
    }
  }
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

Sorry, I added explanations to my code.
